# OkHttpResponseCache returning garbaged text

Tags: okhttp

Has anyone used OkHttpResponseCache on an authenticated HTTPS connection successfully? I'm facing this strange behavior where the second time content is served from cache it return garbage instead of the correct content.

The service I'm using as an example is protected with HTTP basic auth and accessed over HTTPS. I added the must-revalidate response header to allow the cache to store the response. It uses ETags as a mechanism for cache validation.

It works perfectly for the first cached response:

1 - First time I make a service call, the server return 200 OK. Debugging the response cache source code I could see the response if being passed to the put() method (which stores it in the file store).

2 - The second request is made. Server is hit and returns a 304 response. Checking the cache headers and step debugging confirmed me that the server indeed returned 304. One strange behavior tough: on the second response (now served by the cache), the ETag header now contains the value duplicated (instead of having a single value, it has this value in a list twice).

3 - I make a third request. Same behavior as above, same "duplication" of the ETag value but when I get the input stream, instead of the correct json text, I get garbage (as in a bunch of black diamonds with an interrogation inside).

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong (when configuring the cache). I don't know if this is an encoding problem, or if the cache tried to update the file store and messed the input up. I suspect after the first cache response (in the second attempt) the presence of a second ETag value invalidates the headers and the cache attempts to store the response once again and ends messing it up. I wasn't able to step debug through it to confirm yet.

I tried to "translate" the garbage text with UTF-8, 16, ASCII, ISO to no avail. I tried using HTTP instead of HTTPS and got the same behavior.

Did someone encounter something similar and was able to solve it? Is it a bug in the cache or could I be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in the way that OkHttp updates the `Content-Encoding: gzip` header when doing conditional GETs. It's fixed in the OkHttp 1.3.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it again later when I have the time.